# Typescript type to accept keys of an object that map to a particular value type

Tags: typescript, types

I am trying to write a function that accepts an object, along with a key of that object that returns a value of a certain type. For example:

```js
function <T, K extends KeysMatching<T, boolean>>(obj: T, flagKey: K): boolean {
  return obj[flagKey];
}
```

Based on other posts, I have defined `KeysMatching` as

```js
type KeysMatching<T, V> = { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never }[keyof T];
```

However, in trying to use it, I get an error like:
`T[T[keyof T] extends V ? keyof T : never]' is not comparable to type 'V'`

My read of this error is that it should work: satisfying the inner constraint such that it doesn't resolve to `never` seems to imply that the key maps to type `V`. `tsc` seems to disagree, so I'm probably misunderstanding something. Any suggestions on how to define such a type?

Comment: [My attempt to reproduce this seems to work fine, can you give a repro?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQGIBsCGyDSqAngDwAqANIvoqgB5SpgAmAztcawLI5QQAWMMMnJUARnDhZUOMAD45ACjhiAVgC5ElRMFwFim-AEpNEqTKQBvAFCJEAJ3Qh7SFaoDauvISIBdANzWAL7W1gD0YYgAQjisqMyICIlQ-Kj2iAAOcKxQrFQAkoj8OABuqIjMqMBC8RxE3LwCQsiIsaFQRBnlPg18gsKiiABqcogAvIiWiO40QogA1sRwwFq+ALQA-JpkM760DExsw4gb1IiaYKhl6UHui0TLq4HWEAg5ieOTtnY6kpoARGIcPZ-hRvnYgfZNFB7CBUGCQi83lBEGA4AB9RysEBYFETNCYPQ+ZRUf7AST-IyICKIACC9mQIAAtkwUY8Ol1EAByMkUrmIGDsNEo2KsGDIMA4MTSRBQOCZYE4FmMdLszrlHmQ-5cgB0SLA7yxOLxKHQ2G8xBJiEBwMpgSAA)

Comment: @CRice I believe you should write an answer

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's a typescript version issue: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3&strict=true#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcCyBDYBjAFgSwHYHMAeAFQBooA1APigF4oBvKAbRijygGt4B7AMyjEAugFoA-AC5BrIVAgAPYBFwATBJShjYUKbggA3CACcoAX2bcQ-QUIDcAKFCQoAZWBG8+AMI8ANiRp6OERUDBwCEnIEd08qB3t0HlxoqB46RnsoLKg+Hh4pACIAIxQjAtJM7JKjKXcAVwgK03t7PjrcdGBsJKhojwIKFF8GgBllfGBMSNh4OUVlNVcYgh9-YioqAAoeIoArKTIuKWCASl06gFsi4wysxOTgKH0hqT7PdJ3diztKowhgOpGXBPIYAOl840mDmaQA

Comment: @GregSoltis please try it in the playground

Comment: Yup, looks like it's a version issue. My link above has an older version, with an error. Here's the same code with a newer version: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.2&strict=true#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcCyBDYBjAFgSwHYHMAeAFQBooA1APigF4oBvKAbRijygGt4B7AMyjEAugFoA-AC5BrIVAgAPYBFwATBJShjYUKbggA3CACcoAX2bcQ-QUIDcAKFCQoAZWBG8+AMI8ANiRp6OERUDBwCEnIEd08qB3t0HlxoqB46RnsoLKg+Hh4pACIAIxQjAtJM7JKjKXcAVwgK03t7PjrcdGBsJKhojwIKFF8GgBllfGBMSNh4OUVlNVcYgh9-YioqAAoeIoArKTIuKWCASl06gFsi4wysxOTgKH0hqT7PdJ3diztKowhgOpGXBPIYAOl840mDmaQA